# QOpenGLWidget overriding projection matrix

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5

I am using Qt 5.4 and setting up the projection matrix and viewport as follows in my resizeGL function override:

```
glViewport(_off_x, _off_y, _width, _height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, _width, 0, _height, -1, 1);
```

I can verify this and when I print out the projection matrix as follows, it shows the correct value:

```
GLdouble projection[16];
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection );
// printing this shows the correct projection matrix.
```

However, somewhere this is getting overridden. When I print the projection matrix in the paintGL() function, it shows it as identity.

Interestingly, I switched to the old QGLWidget and it performs as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, somewhere this is getting overridden. When I print the projection matrix in the paintGL() function, it shows it as identity.

And you're surprised exactly why? Qt5 may use OpenGL for drawing its stuff. Which means that Qt will have to set the state of the OpenGL context according to its needs.

What you observed is what is to be expected, so don't be surprised.

> I am using Qt 5.4 and setting up the projection matrix and viewport as follows in my resizeGL function override:

You should not be doing that. As with every state based system it's essential to set the state right when you need it to what you need it – or keep track of all of the state changes, which is much more difficult.

Do the right thing and move everything you did in `resizeGL` to where it belongs: `paintGL`. The sole purpose of `resizeGL` is to update resources like FBO renderbuffers and to reflect the new size. But don't use it to set drawing related OpenGL state.

Comment: I am sorry I do not agree. I am not sure why I need to set the projection and viewports and all this every time in the paint call. This is completely unnecessary. The old widget works as expected and in my view, the new one is broken. If you set the viewport and projection matrices, the widget should respect that.

Comment: Also, from qt docs (5.4) : resizeGL() - Sets up the OpenGL viewport, projection, etc. Gets called whenever the widget has been resized (and also when it is shown for the first time because all newly created widgets get a resize event automatically).

Comment: @Luca: The viewport and projection matrices are OpenGL state variables. It's perfectly fine, and actually very common to repeatedly change their values – for example everytime you see a minimap, some navigation HUD or some overview window this has been done by means of changing the viewport and projection halfway through. Nowhere in the OpenGL specification it is told that frameworks should respect them. Also the whole `resizeGL` and `reshape` function mess was started by GLUT and ever since application frameworks seem to have parroted it.

Comment: @Luca:  Just move the whole stuff to paintGL. Trust me, there are **zero** performance benefits of having it in `resizeGL`. *And regarding modern OpenGL the whole discussion is a moot point anyway!* In modern OpenGL there's no longer a transformation matrix state; you're supposed to set them yourself in shader uniform variables. And the viewport, well, you'll going to switch that a number of times if using FBOs anyway.

Comment: I see your point but my issue is that Qt is inconsistent with respect to the old widget and nowhere in the documentation that they mention this change. Thanks for your comments. I will switch to the new widget and add this to the paint call.

Comment: By the way, you seem to know about this. What is a good resource to learn this "modern OpenGL". Seems internet is full of bad OpenGL tutorials!

Comment: @Luca: The problem with "growing up" with these changes is, that you learn them by experimentation, and occasionally writing the tutorials yourself, so there's some bias. I'm quite fond of the tutorial written by NicolBolas (aka Jason L. McKesson) – unfortunately for some reason there's radio silence from him for a worryingly long time; his domain registration actually went down! So recently I've set up a mirror on my own server http://opengl.datenwolf.net/gltut/html/index.html – however a lot of people complain about this tutorial, that it's written for people already knowing OpenGL.

Comment: This is very helpful and kind of you. Many thanks. I plan to spend some time learning about 3D graphics and I am sure this will be quite useful.

Comment: @Luca: Other than that the tutorials we've collected over at the http://reddit.com/r/opengl sidebar are well respected.

Comment: By the way, a lot of the pages on your mirror site comes with 403: Forbidden error

Comment: @Luca: oops, should be fixed now